# AD DS it doesn't show any info event

Tags: windows-server-2008

In Role services in the AD DS role summary, it doesn't show any information. Previously it was showing information.

Is this good or bad? Do I need to correct something?

Comment: "What Changed?" -- It behaved one way, now it's behaving another, therefore something changed.  Computers do not change on their own, so someone must have changed something: determine what (and who) and that will tell you whether this is a good thing or bad.

Comment: i had an warning 1020, and i was searching for this error on microsoft page and i follow the instructions from there. It was a problem with an Certificate. The warning disappeared, and there after no more infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize after in the right side where is the Filter Events and it was not checked the Information box.
Since i checked that box it shows the info